# Regex: Not to Match with Repeating Dots

Tags: regex

This Alex's regex at [the manual notes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#71761),

```
$pattern = '#(^|[^\"\'=\]]{1})(http|HTTP|ftp)(s|S)?://([^\s<>\.]+)\.([^\s<>]+|.[^\.])#sm';
```

also matches truncated uls such as

```
http://goooooooooooo....................gle.com
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier and more readable to execute this regex: `\.{2,}` prior to executing that regex. If it matches, then you know that at some point in your regex, you have at least two periods following each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think better to use this:

```
'#(^|[^\"\'=\]]{1})(http|HTTP|ftp)(s|S)?://(([A-Za-z0-9_-]+(\.[A-Za-z]+)+)#sm';
```

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment. Anyway `[^\s<>]+` allows `..`

Comment: It doesn't match `..` alright, but as of its current form, it doesn't match a full URL. Anyway, the original one also have lots of problem of its own and writing a regex to match a URL correctly is not an easy task.

Comment: But URL can't contains `..` chars

Comment: The original one with `[^\s<>]+` allow the regex to match a full URL (with path, query string, etc.), although it matches wrong stuffs such as `..`. Your current one only match up to the domain part.